# Convergence Rate of "Infinite Monkey"-type-probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S$ be a finite set and $n,m\in\mathbb N$. Consider a random variable $R$ uniformly distributed on $S^{n+m}$. I am trying to tackle the probability of the event
\begin{equation}
A_m(n):=\{\exists_{1\leq i<j\leq m}: (R_i,\dots,R_{i+n-1}) = (R_j,\dots,R_{j+n-1})\}
\end{equation}
as $m\to\infty$. I managed to prove $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb P(A_m(n)) = 1$, since the event "$(R_i,\dots,R_{i+n-1})=r$ infinitely often" constitutes a lower bound for every $r\in S^n$ and has probability $1$ using Borel-Cantelli (note that here we extend the process $R$ to be $(R_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ with all $R_i$ iid and uniformly distributed on $S$).

I am now trying to find the rate of convergence of $\mathbb P(A_m(n))$ depending on $n$. My initial idea was to find a suitable subset of $A_m(n)$ to at least get a lower bound. However I am struggling to do so.

This question seems to be related to the Infinite Monkey Theorem for which formulas for the expected hitting time of a certain word exist. But here I do not need to hit a specific word. Rather one is interested in hitting any word of length $n$ twice when hitting $n+m$ keys on the keyboard. For this I couldn't find a source.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but if $m-n+1\geq |S|^n$ then $\mathbb{P}(A_m(n))=1$ by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Asking intuitively: should one even expect the convergence rate to be somewhat exponential in $m$?

Comment: Cross-posted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468024/what-is-the-convergence-rate-of-this-infinite-monkey-type-probability